# ParseException in Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to use a `UDF` in hive. But when I try to create a temporary function using  `userdate as 'unixtimeToDate'`, I get this exception

```
hive> create temporary function userdate1 as 'unixtimeToDate';
FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 character ' ' not supported here
line 1:35 character ' ' not supported here
```

I am not sure why the character is not supported. Could I get some guidance on this please.

Answer (score 8):

The exception is clear enough here, you have an error in your SQL. You have a **full width space** in your SQL. More about [Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)

```
hive> create temporary function userdate1 as 'unixtimeToDate';
                                        ^^^here, you have a full width space
```

Answer (score 1):

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: line .. character ' ' not supported here

In my situation, it's because the `' '` is not a normal `space`. I replaced them all and it's OK.

Comment: I am facing this issue in DbVis, how did you replace space with space ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is syntax for adding jar in hive

```
ADD JAR absolute_path_of_jar_file;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION function_name AS 'packagename.ClassName';
```